# Error building ROS on OSX with latest developer tools 5.1

Tags: boost, ros-hydro, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've encountered this error building ROS on OSX. As far as I can figure, this started happening after I upgraded my developer tools to the latest version (5.1):

```
/usr/local/include/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-atomic.hpp:961:64: error: no matching
      constructor for initialization of 'storage_type' (aka
      'boost::atomics::detail::storage128_type')
    explicit base_atomic(value_type const& v) BOOST_NOEXCEPT : v_(0)
                                                               ^  ~
/usr/local/include/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-atomic.hpp:932:28: note: candidate
      constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known
      conversion from 'int' to 'const boost::atomics::detail::storage128_type'
      for 1st argument
struct BOOST_ALIGNMENT(16) storage128_type
                           ^
/usr/local/include/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-atomic.hpp:932:28: note: candidate
      constructor (the implicit default constructor) not viable: requires 0
      arguments, but 1 was provided
```

It looks like this is problem with some of the dependencies for TF or TF2, and is causing a large number of things to fail to build properly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140326/error-building-ros-on-osx-with-latest-developer-tools-5.1/) by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like this is a bug/change in the latest version of the developer tools.

Homebrew has released the appropriate boost patches from upstream in [this issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/27396), but you have to uninstall and reinstall boost to get them. I had to do:

```
brew update
brew reinstall boost
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-15**:
This is correct. Same for me, or rather `brew reinstall boost` :P

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-19**:
Boost should now be updated in `brew upgrade`, so no manual reinstall is needed for those who have not done it already. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/27660